# Node Js refresh auth token

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, token

How can you provide example for refresh node js auth token? I mean by what the parameters can I refresh auth token? For example if I can refresh it by login and password then where should I store this params for single-page app? As I understand store it in cookie is not good idea for security, localstorage is not good also because some of browsers not supported it. So maybe someone know another way for refresh token?

Comment: Have you looked for any node packages that handle tokens or are you trying to role your own?

Comment: I'm using sails js for my project and this is real time app, and I want to have fully control for it. So I just want to know how other guys resolve this issue. Or maybe if you know any ready great packages just let me know please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created AuthToken model that contain these fields:

```
user_id, access_token, refresh_token, access_token_expiration
```

After successful  user login, server side will send `refresh_token` and `access_token` to client side and store it to localstorage(cookies for old browsers).

And all subsequent requests will be sent with `access_token`(I use header x-access-token for $httpProvider in angular).

When token expires, client needs to send `refresh_token` for updating `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `expiration date`. Since I use sockets I can refresh access_token if it is expired in any request(for this I send z-refresh-token header also for each request) so I shouldn't send any extra request and I can keep current user request, just will return tokens via socket event after it was updated.

*Hope this helps*

Comment: So if i intercept and get hold of a refresh token , i have free access to new tokens and the api , doesn't seem very secure or is there something im missing here ?

Comment: How to tell client to send refreshToken when acceccToken expires?

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are a very secure storage mechanism, if used correctly.  Local storage should never be used for authentication information.  OWASP has a great write-up on storage security:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Storage_APIs

To quote the important parts:

- > Do not store session identifiers in local storage as the data is always accessible by JavaScript. Cookies can mitigate this risk using the `httpOnly` flag.
- > [With local storage] There is no way to restrict the visibility of an object to a specific path like with the attribute path of HTTP Cookies, every object is shared within an origin and protected with the Same Origin Policy. Avoid host multiple applications on the same origin, all of them would share the same localStorage object, use different subdomains instead.

Back to your original question: where to store the refresh token?  Answer: In a `HttpOnly` cookie.  This prevents the cookie from being stolen by XSS attacks, and it makes it very easy for your server to issue new access tokens (using the refresh token) because the server will have access to both at the same time, on the same request.

You can add another layer and encrypt the entire refresh token that is stored in the cookie.

Caution: when using cookies, you also need to protect yourself against [CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

I’ve written at length about front-end security and JWTs in these two blog posts:

[Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps (SPAs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-secure-user-interfaces-using-jwts/)

[https://stormpath.com/blog/build-secure-user-interfaces-using-jwts/](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/)

Disclaimer : I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com), our service gives you a secure, hosted user database with many features.  Our [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express) module makes it very easy to get started with login and registration flows for your application.  We are in the process of writing a new release, and it will be using access tokens in the way that I describe in this answer.